# I need a formula to calculate gml:pos to standard GPS coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, wfs, gps, maps, gml

I downloaded "address points" data from geoportal and the coordinates are not readable for me.

```
<wfs:member>
  <ms:prg-adresy>
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2180">
            <gml:lowerCorner>486756.211500 638033.957900</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>486756.211500 638033.957900</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <ms:msGeometry>
      <gml:Point gml:id=".1" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2180">
        <gml:pos>486756.211500 638033.957900</gml:pos>
      </gml:Point>
    </ms:msGeometry>
    <ms:miejscowosc>Warszawa</ms:miejscowosc>
    <ms:ulica>Plac Trzech Krzyży</ms:ulica>
    <ms:numer>16B</ms:numer>
    <ms:teryt>146501</ms:teryt>
    <ms:simc>0918123</ms:simc>
    <ms:ulic>38542</ms:ulic>
    <ms:kod>00-507</ms:kod>
  </ms:prg-adresy>
</wfs:member>
```

I have only one problem with decoding this GML/XML. How to convert "486756.211500 638033.957900" to standard GPS coordinates in geographical degrees?

What is the exact formula for converting this data into geographical degrees? I need precision to a million part of the degree to connect the points addresses with building outline (from another website).

I found nothing with Google about it.

Comment: You are looking for projection code, which one depends on your language

Comment: @IanTurton The formula can be written in math, php, pure javascript (without dollars), C, C++. I know many programming languages and mathematical notation. I found this site now: https://epsg.io/2180 but I must translate 331500 points. I don't want to send 300k GETs to this server... I do not understand "Attributes" on this website. How to use them to translate to degrees?

Comment: As noted on the linked page, this is a Transverse Mercator projection with specific parameters. You might have more luck googling conversions for that more general projection and then input the parameters specified on the webpage. This github search may also help: https://github.com/search?q=ETRF2000-PL&type=code

Comment: The easiest way to do this is via the PROJ library, which you can call from many programming languages or via its own command-line tools. What can you code in? The point in your data translates to 21.0217392235777,52.2295279595857 in EPSG code 4326, which is one (of many) lat-long possibilities but is the usual "GPS Coordinates" code.

Comment: BarryCarter I cannot open your link. It doesn't work for me. 
Spacedman I dont want to link external libraries. I only need one probably easy formula to calculate gml:pos(Y,X) to gps(long,lat). No more. 
Math formula or simple function to translate it.

Comment: No one writes new projection code, use the tried and tested library in the programming language of your choice

Comment: Oh, and you don't need a millionth of a degree to hot a building

Comment: I just asked that and nothing else. I don't want any your code... 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#From_UTM_coordinates_.28E.2C_N.2C_Zone.2C_Hemi.29_to_latitude.2C_longitude_.28.CF.86.2C_.CE.BB.29

40 lines of code instead of multiple files of external library... Returns the same results as https://epsg.io/2180 (and will work faster than an external library).

Comment: If you resolved your problem you can write it as an answer. The large coordinate transformation libraries are written to support maybe thousands of different coordinate systems and it is natural that you can handle one transformation with less code. It should still be possible to find your transformation from the source code of Proj or GeoTools or some other library because they do handle also that transformation among others.

Comment: EPSG:2180 is according to EPSG (EPSG.org) `Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: northing, easting (x,y). Orientations: north, east. UoM: m` so you have `gml:pos(X,Y)` not `gml:pos(Y,X)` as your starting point

Comment: It's unlikely that geocoded addresses will be within 11cm of the building footprint, so your requirements need review.

Comment: Formula you are citing from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#From_UTM_coordinates_.28E.2C_N.2C_Zone.2C_Hemi.29_to_latitude.2C_longitude_.28.CF.86.2C_.CE.BB.29 refers to UTM. Which zone did you take when doing your calculations for Poland (EPSG:2180)?